# compare two strings using grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
echo "abc-vcu def" | grep -w "abc.vcu" 
echo $?
```

The output of the above line is `0`. But `abc-vcu` != `abc.vcu` and `def` != `abc.vcu`. So it should return `1`.

Command is returning true because it is assuming `.` and `-` are same. How to do exact comparing?

Comment: Why not use Bash's `[[`?

Comment: if you use it in script, you may want to add the `-q` option to grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to use `grep` in this case, use it as follows:

```
echo "abc-vcu def" | grep -F -w "abc.vcu"
```

`man grep` says that with `-F` grep must

> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings

This fixes the problem that `.` is recognized as 'any symbol' pattern.

Comment: omm... a bit strange. -F is specified by POSIX. Looks like you need to screen `.` by `\.`. `echo "$x" | grep -w "${y//./\\.}"`

Answer (score 2):

In grep `.` means **any character** (regular expression syntax)

If you need to match `.` try `\.`

```
echo "abc-vcu def" | grep -w "abc\.vcu"
echo $?
```

Comment: that works but what if we have two variables : x and y. x can contain more than 1 string and y contains a single string. x and y are random inputs by user. This wont work in that case.

Comment: Would you please not undo the edits that escape `\.`?

Comment: @LutzHorn: Sorry, that was not on purpose. It seems we were editing at the same time.

Comment: x can be "abc.fs def" and y can be "abc-fs". x and y are input given by users. and command is echo "$x" | grep -w "$y". echo $?. now this will again return 0. and we cant include "/" in string y as it is user input.

Comment: echo "abc-vcu def" | grep -w "^abc\.vcu$"
    echo $?

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting is better achieved with a simple string comparison.

```
if [[ "abc-vcu def" == *"abc.vcu"* ]]; then
    echo "String B contained in String A"
else
    echo "No containment"
fi
```

Notice also how this avoids the antipattern of examining `$?`.  Just to elaborate, anything that looks like

```
command
if [ $? == 0 ]; then ...
```

is better written as

```
if command; then ...
```

Tangentially, if you really do want or have to use `grep`, there are some options you need to understand.  `grep` matches regular expressions, not just strings.  There is a separate option to change the search expression into a string, namely `-F` (traditionally available as a separate command `fgrep`):

```
echo moo | grep m.o     # true
echo moo | grep -F m.o  # false
```

Just for completeness, note also that `grep` looks for a match anywhere in the input.  So `echo moo | grep o` is true.  If you really want to look for an exact match, you need the `-x` option (or change the expression you are grepping for):

```
echo moo | grep -x moo
echo moo | grep '^moo$'
```

Like @Kent remarks, `grep` will print any matching lines by default, which you probably don't want here -- you are only running `grep` to see if there is a match.  So you need the `-q` flag as well.   To summarize,

```
echo "abc-vcu def" | grep -Fxwq "abc.vcu"
```

Finally, you should probably also be aware of `case`:

```
case "abc-vcu def" in *"abc.vcu"*) echo true;; *) echo false;; esac
```

Unlike the `[[` Bash-only test, `case` is portable all the way back to the original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `grep` you could let `bash` do the work, especially if you intend to use variables anyway:

```
string1='abc-vcu def'
string2='abc.vcu'
[[ ! ${string1/*${string2}*/} ]]
echo $?
```

`[[ expression ]]` returns `0` or `1` depending on the evaluation of `expression`.

`!` is a *logical not*.

`${parameter/pattern/string}` replaces the first occurence of `pattern` in `parameter` by `string`, where `pattern` is expanded just as in pathname expansions. For the above case that means that if `$string2` appears anywhere in `$string1`, `$string1` is completely replaced by `''` (an empty string), which is a *logical false*.